# Mono (mod_mono) & Apachen Debian doesn't process aspx page

Tags: apache, mono, debian, mod-mono

I'm trying to develop a simple website and deploy on Apache + mod_mono+ debian.

Apache fails to render the aspx pages  with a compiler error. Here's is the aspx code and error details .
System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException
: Unhandled Exception:
Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Details: : Unhandled Exception:

Error origin: Compiler

Error source file: /dev/one.aspx

Exception stack trace:

at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0

Version Information: 3.0.0 (master-experimental/3f84403 Wed Oct 24 20:38:33 CEST 2012); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1

Im a newbie to Linux environment. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using mod-mono-server4? That error used to appear to me when I was hosting a .Net 4.0 application with mod-mono-server2. Add this to the end of your httpd.conf file: "MonoServerPath default path_to_mod-mono-server-4". To know the path use "whereis mod-mono-server4".